# How to decrement a value in another table via a trigger? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, triggers

I want my trigger to decrement the quantity by 1 in the table "quantity" when a new row is added to "rented_equipment_log" where date_returned has a value of NULL.

A basic synopsis of the database is that there is an equipment table with columns; model, maker, type and quantity. (E.g. 1001, 'Jackson', 'oar', 10)

The table rented_equipment_log has the columns; member_id, model, type, date_taken, date_returned. (E.g. 17225663, 1001, oar, 2018-11-26, 2018-11-27)

So when a member takes out a piece of equipment but has not yet returned it (date_returned is null), the quantity of the same model decrements by 1 in the table equipment.

However I'm getting a syntax error. I've looked at other questions similar to this and still can't figure out what the error is.

Here's the trigger:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateQuantity 
AFTER INSERT ON rented_equipment_log
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE q integer;
    SELECT quantity INTO q FROM equipment WHERE model = NEW.model; 
    IF (date_returned IS NULL) THEN
    UPDATE equipment
    SET quantity = q -1 WHERE model = NEW.model
END IF;
END;//
```

And here's the error: 
     #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
     near 
     'END IF;
     END' at line 9

Comment: A `;` after `new.model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting an error there.  But your query is more complicated than necessary:

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER UpdateQuantity 
AFTER INSERT ON rented_equipment_log
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE equipment e
        SET e.quantity = e.quantity - 1
        WHERE e.model = NEW.model and ?.date_returned IS NULL;
END;//
```

I'm not sure if `date_returned` should be `new.date_returned` or `e.date_returned`.  I don't even understand that condition.  I would be expecting `e.equipment > 0`.

Comment: I believe also you need to add "AND date_returned IS NULL"

Comment: Hi, firstly thanks for the solution. After trying this I realised what was wrong. Basically in my procedure to add a new row to "rented_equipment_log" I didn't have "date_returned" as a parameter - so when I tried this trigger it gave me an error saying that there was an "unknown column" (date_returned) in the where clause. I removed it from your trigger and now everything is working smoothly. We don't need "date_returned" in the 'AddLoan' procedure as the person has not returned it yet. Thank you for your help!